# Flash Tlf looks bad in flash professional CS5.5

Tags: flash, text, tlf, flash-cs5.5

Just drawing a simple text line.

With TLF text it looks pixelated and with classic text it looks just fine.
[image]

Looks at the 's' and the 'r' they looks bad with TLF text.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Do you use pure AS or the Flash IDE to create the TLF TextFields?

Comment: FYI, TLF looks terrible.  Even in the designer, it looks completely different at runtime, plus the whole system is plagued with problems, especially with child SWFs loaded at runtime that use the TLF.  And it's not just the "there's a preloader wrapper", it's like.. if you don't load it into the same app domain, the TLF fields (just the ones with named instances!) don't show up at all, and even if you do load it into the same domain, the fonts are all wrong, or uninitialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, it's probably because classic text uses anti-aliasing, and you probably don't use it with the TLF text.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing

Answer (score 0):

If you create the TLFTextField using pure AS, try to add custom antialiasing:

```
tlf.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
```